# How to handle mutiple clicks on popBackStack() in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-navigation

When i click on back icon multiple times it calls navController.popBackStack() that many times and leaves me with a blank screen.
How to deal with it?

```
 Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                PhotoDetailTopBar(
                    onBackClick = {
                        navController.popBackStack()
                    },
                    onInfoClick = { isSheetOpen = true }
                )
            }
        )
```

I want the navController.popBackStack() to sleep/disable until it finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get blank screen because there are no more destinations on the back stack to be popped.

Method `popBackStack()` returns false if back stack was empty and nothing was popped. For more details look at the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#popBackStack()).

You might want to do something like this

```
if(!navController.popBackStack()){
   //navigate to starting screen of your app
   navController.navigate("route_of_starting_screen")
}
```

Comment: An alternate approach is to call navHostController.popBackStack("route_of_previous_screen", false)